# Send message with Facebook Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have already included this in my page html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And that I have `facebook-like box` in my page already, however I need to do now a way to send messages to email using the Facebook Javascript API. Is this configuration enough to call a "send message"?

I have a custom HTML form in which when I click send I like it to send a message on my Facebook page's behalf. I have my page up in Facebook.

- I need to send message without any server side component (pure Javascript)
- I have a existing Facebook page (which I will use to send messages with)
- I have a custom form in which will be used to type in message.
- The message will be sent to some specific email address
- I can send to any email with Facebook so I assume this will work

Comment: Here is a gist I made for a function that provides this service for a chrome extension: https://gist.github.com/VehpuS/916bdb9cc5ce287cf29c8708d79380a6

I imagine with a little work this might become a proper solution to this question (i.e. not one that's tailor-made for chrome extensions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer your questions separately:

- I need to send message without any server side component (pure
  Javascript)

**If it can be a simple message to a facebook user, you have to use the FB.ui send dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/
That´s pretty much the only way for you, you can just try putting in an email address in the popup. According to the documentation, it should work.**

- I have a custom form in which will be used to type in message.

**That´s where even the send dialog will not work anymore. You cannot prefill the message parameter, what you want would only be possible with the PHP SDK of Facebook. But then again: Why would you program the textfield on your own, if Facebook already offers everything in that dialog?**

Without that dialog, there is no way to just send a message in the background without a server side language like PHP.

Comment: FB.ui send dialog looks like neat solution, it needs that the viewer of the page to be logged in with his/her facebook account

Comment: Of course the user needs to be logged in, but he does not have to authorize the app. And if the user is not logged in, facebook will open a login dialog without any further required code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: here is the source [Facebook send message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // assume we are already logged in
      FB.init({appId: '123050457758183', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
          });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I forgot to state that, I like to do this without the popup login and things like that...  send in behalf of a user given a authorization key or something...

Comment: What do you mean is.. even if you're not login on facebook but you are login on your website.. you can still send message is that what you mean?

Comment: do not use the synchronous way to include the javascript sdk, always the asynchronous as recommended by facebook

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers. You might want to make a function.

```
<div class="facebook-invite">
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root">
        <a href="#" onclick="FBInvite()">Invite Facebook Friends</a>
    </div>
    <script>

      FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXX', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
        function FBInvite(){

      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'Join This website it is cool',
          link: 'rishabhjainiitbhu.ac.in',
          });
         }
     </script>
</div>
```

This will make a link, clickin on which the dialog box will pop up.